# Near and large values overlaps each others in line chart

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

Thank you for this powerful library.
I have a problem when the values are near to each other and every value has several amount of digits, the value would overlap each others like in the below snapshot.
I tried to make some values upper and some lower the line, or to make values written in vertical way (like x labels in the snapshot), but I didn't find way to do that.

If there is any advice or other workaround, it will be appreciated.

Snapshot is in the link below

[Image Shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtC4X.png)

Comment: need to change in chart library!

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara thank you for your reply. Could you or anyone else give me suggestions for what and/or where to change ?